# Best algorithms, image processing techinques used to compare images

Tags: image, algorithm, templates, ocr

I need to compare a set of scanned tshirt tag label images with a master tag label image in order to find the differences between them. The requirement is to identify the

- image size difference
- character content difference and size difference
- color difference
- image content positioning difference

Finally everything should be measured and output the image matching percentage as a result. Please explain the suitable algorithm and image processing techniques to build this solution.